# Automatically add rows and column data together while using loop to generate table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition

I am creating a form where the column and rows should automatically add their data, but I have to generate the name based on DB data and have to use a loop to add details. Adding column is perfect but adding the rows is quite difficult here :)

> How can I add rows and column together by one input data? And also add last column total (which is not editable)

Notes: My input rows will be generated using loop function, so if you want to change `class-name`, `id` etc, then change inside both table rows.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance, you can find the snippet here below:

```js
$(document).on('input', '.outstanding, .received, .paid', updateSchedule26);

function updateSchedule26() {
  var sum = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, out, reci, paid;
  $('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        out = $(this).val();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        reci = $(this).val();
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        paid = $(this).val()
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  var total = (parseInt(out) + parseInt(reci)) + parseInt(paid);
  $(".amtOutstanding").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_received').val(sum2.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_paid').val(sum3.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val($(".amtOutstanding").val());
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Outstanding(+)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Received(-)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Paid(=)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Sub Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Add Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_outstanding" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_received" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_paid" class="form-control" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_amtOutstanding" class="form-control" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Ary you need function for dynamically create table ?

Comment: No, I used a PHP foreachloop to create tables rows based on DB values

Comment: So, you need a script that will work for any number of rows and columns in a table, right?

Comment: yeah exactly, you can see my snippet code. Column added is working there, but rows are not!

Comment: For now, in my database, I have only two names `name1` and `name2` that's why I put two rows in my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can update rows and columns separate, like this:

```js
$(document).on('input', '.outstanding, .received, .paid', updateTable);

function updateTable() {
  updateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
  updateCol($(this).closest("td"), $(this));
  updateTotal($(this.closest("table")));
}

function updateRow($row) {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0;
  $row.find('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        out = $(this).val();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        reci = $(this).val();
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        paid = $(this).val()
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $row.find('.amtOutstanding').val(sum + sum2 + sum3);
}

function updateCol($col, $input) {
  var index = $col.index() + 1;
  var sum = 0;
  $col.closest('table').find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').find('input').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0 && !$(this).attr('id')) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  if ($input.hasClass('outstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('received')) {
    $('#sch26_received').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('paid')) {
    $('#sch26_paid').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('amtOutstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

}

function updateSchedule26() {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0,
    out, reci, paid;
  $('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        out = $(this).val();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        reci = $(this).val();
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        paid = $(this).val()
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  var total = (parseInt(out) + parseInt(reci)) + parseInt(paid);
  $(".amtOutstanding").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_received').val(sum2.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_paid').val(sum3.toFixed(2));
}

function updateTotal($table) {
  var sum = 0;
  $table.find('.amtOutstanding').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2))
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Outstanding(+)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Received(-)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Paid(=)</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Sub Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Add Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_outstanding" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_received" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_paid" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_amtOutstanding" class="form-control" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly. Thank you.. but in my code `outstanding total column` a numbers 81 is added along with my input data. I used unique `id` and `class name` also

Comment: Hello @SergeyN, do you have any idea why my first column total value added `81` along with my input. If I copy-paste the code you provided here also it's still there. I'm pretty sure that I've used unique `id` and `class-name`. Another column and rows are working fine

Comment: @Vpa do you have other table on this page ?

Comment: I put table `id` and everything's working fine, didn't know that the table `id` should be there . Thank you so much

Comment: last question, how can I make auto-add the last row last column value. (adding of Sub Total) whenever the value is changed

Comment: I updated my code to work with many tables and the sum for the last row.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried but the way how I call my function is not working, anyway thank you so much for helping... Happy coding.